# How can I have horizontal labels around a line in Qgis?

Tags: label, qgis

[image: what i want]

I can't have labels next to the entities when I select "horizontal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Geometry Generator to build a reference geometry:

[image: Offset Labels with Geometry Generator]